# How to make text flash and glow using css

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have this css but doesn't work to make my text glow and flash:

```
 @import
 url(//fonts.googleapis.com/cssfamily=Pacifico);
 body {
 min-height:100vh;
 padding-top:5rem;
 background:
 #112
 url(//images.weserv.nl/url=i.imgur.com/6QJjYMe.jpg)
 center no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 margin: 0;
 overflow:hidden;
 }

.lasvegas {
font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
font-size:80px;
border: none;
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
text-align:
center;
text-shadow: 1px 5px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 0 2px
rgba(255,255,255,1), 0 0 10px
rgba(255,255,255,1),  0 0 20px rgba(255,255,255,1), 0 0
30px rgba(255,255,255,1),  0 0 40px #ff00de,0 0 70px
#ff00de,  0 0 80px #ff00de, 0 0 100px #ff00de;
 }
 .lasvegas
 span {
animation: blink .3s infinite alternate;
}
.lasvegas
span.delay {
animation-duration:6s;
animation-delay: 2s
animation-direction: alternate
cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.2, 0.3,
1.0)
}

@keyframes blink {
0%  {
}

50% {
}

60% {
text-shadow:0 0
2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1), 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, .
4); text-stroke: 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
}

70% {
text-
shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,1), 0 0 10px.
rgba(255,255,255,1), 0 0 20px rgba(255,255,255,1), 0 0
30px rgba(255,255,255,1),  0 0 40px #ff00de, 0 0 70px
#ff00de, 0 0 80px #ff00de,  0 0 100px #ff00de;
}

80% {
text-shadow:0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1), 0 0 10px
rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
text-stroke: 2px
rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
}

100% {
text-shadow: 0 0 2px
rgba(255,255,255,1), 0 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,1), 0 0
20px rgba(255,255,255,1), 0 0 30px rgba(255,255,255,1),0
0 40px #ff00de,0 0 70px #ff00de, 0 0 80px #ff00de, 0 0
100px #ff00de;
}

}
```

This is the html:

```
 <div class="lasvegas"> Neon text 
f<span>ro</span>m<br> Las <span 
class="delay">V</span>egas </div>
```

It should be pink and flash in two different places, at different intervals, like a glowing, flashing neon sign. It's for an events page in wordpress. Im just wondering what I'm missing out here because it should work. All the code is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
 @import
 url(//fonts.googleapis.com/cssfamily=Pacifico);
 body {
 min-height:100vh;
 padding-top:5rem;
 background:
 #112
 url(//images.weserv.nl/url=i.imgur.com/6QJjYMe.jpg)
 center no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 margin: 0;
 overflow:hidden;
 }

.lasvegas {
font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
font-size:80px;
border: none;
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
text-align:
center;
text-shadow: 1px 5px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.3), 0 0 2px
rgba(255,255,255,1), 0 0 10px
rgba(255,255,255,1),  0 0 20px rgba(255,255,255,1), 0 0
30px rgba(255,255,255,1),  0 0 40px #ff00de,0 0 70px
#ff00de,  0 0 80px #ff00de, 0 0 100px #ff00de;
 }
 .lasvegas
 span {
animation: blink .3s infinite alternate;
}
.lasvegas
span.delay {
animation-duration:6s;
animation-delay: 2s
animation-direction: alternate
cubic-bezier(0.5, 0.2, 0.3,
1.0)
}

@keyframes blink {
0%  {
}

50% {
}

60% {
text-shadow:0 0
2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1), 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, .
4); text-stroke: 2px rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
}

70% {
text-
shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,1), 0 0 10px.
rgba(255,255,255,1), 0 0 20px rgba(255,255,255,1), 0 0
30px rgba(255,255,255,1),  0 0 40px #ff00de, 0 0 70px
#ff00de, 0 0 80px #ff00de,  0 0 100px #ff00de;
}

80% {
text-shadow:0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1), 0 0 10px
rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
text-stroke: 2px
rgba(255,255,255,0.05);
}

100% {
text-shadow: 0 0 2px
rgba(255,255,255,1), 0 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,1), 0 0
20px rgba(255,255,255,1), 0 0 30px rgba(255,255,255,1),0
0 40px #ff00de,0 0 70px #ff00de, 0 0 80px #ff00de, 0 0
100px #ff00de;
}

}
```

```html
<div class="lasvegas"><span> Neon text 
from<br></span> <span class="delay">Las Vegas</span> </div>
```

I don't know what you want to see exactly but it behaves like you defined it:

fROm flashes fast.
The V from Vegas flashes slowly.

Please be more specific with your question.

Edit: now it flashes slower after the line break..

Comment: Great. Thanks. But possible to separate the words out a bit. In jsfiddle.net looks great, on the page turns out like this: https://adsler.co.uk/events/

Comment: Just checked your source code. You put the the text itself in a div with the class "entry-content". Maybe check the style you applied to this class. If my solution works like expected, mark it as the correct answer and ask a new answer if you need more help.